# UIPickerView as inputView of UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I've read a lot about how I can use a `UIPickerView` as the `inputView` of my `UITextField`. The thing is, I am able to call the `UIPickerView` when I tap on the `UITextField`. However, my app always loads with the `UIPickerView` shown. I have already tried changing the `myownpickerview.hidden = YES;` in `viewDidLoad`, but this causes problems when I click on the `UITextField`. It won't show up, and if I click multiple times, the debugger shows that there would be an error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I only want the `UIPickerView` shown after I tap on the `UITextField`

I'm still working on my first ever iOS app. Please be patient. Thank you =)

Comment: Welcome to iOS development, it's a great place!  Where did you read about this?

Comment: yes you call the pickerview in textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: @meaning-matters I read about all these on stackoverflow. Great place with lots of great people =D

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this, it works fine, put it in viewdidload.

```
yourpicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 150)];
    [yourpicker setDataSource: self];
    [yourpicker setDelegate: self];
    yourpicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.yourtextfield.inputView = yourpicker;
```

**do not** `[self.view addSubview: yourpicker];` this

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the frame. Am I supposed to position it out of the screen? If so, will it come back when I click on the `UITextField`, and how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: SilverHood, it shouldn't show until the user taps on the UITextField. Perhaps you are allocating another UIPickerView somewhere else? The code should just use this one.

Comment: i have edited my answer and wrote a note check that or dont add pickerview as subview .

Comment: @auspicious99 does it matter that I created the `UIPickerView` using the storyboard? I dragged and dropped it there. Right now, if I don't add `self.` in front of my `UIPickerView` name, I get errors

Comment: @AkleshRathaur I've accepted your answer. I copied your code exactly, just that I added `self.` in front of my `UIPickerView`'s name. Doing so actually leaves 2 lines on the screen (I presume it's the selection indicator), but no matter how I do it, it doesn't go away. The only way is to drag the `UIPickerView` on the Storyboard all the way down. Any solutions for this? Other than that, thank you very much!

Comment: @SilverHood you should create the `UIPickerView` programatically, as a property inside your view controller. For example, `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *yourPicker;`. Also, there is no need to set the frame, you can do it like this `self.yourPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that helped me too, but How can i make the UIPickerView disappear after the user selects a value in it?

Comment: @Marlon please put "[self.view endediting:yes]" in didselect row of pickerview.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this,

```
 // Picker
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,150)];
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;

// Tool bar
UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,35)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

// Bar button
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneButtonTapped:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[pickerToolbar setItems:@[flexSpace,doneButton]];

self.selectedLockerTextFiled.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar;
self.selectedLockerTextFiled.inputView = picker;
```

Below code for done button actions,

```
-(void)pickerDoneButtonTapped:(id)picker{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift:

```swift
let pickerView = UIPickerView()
pickerView.dataSource = self
pickerView.delegate = self
textField.inputView = pickerView;
```

Don't forget to implement the `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`.