# ios drop down menu on button click

Tags: ios

I have found the following [site](https://gist.github.com/ktuite/fc23de2f129458630f18/download#) with code that is supposed to reveal a button and once clicked, it shows a drop down menu. No button was shown and hence feature can't be tested.

Am I missing something? Do I have to create an element in the UI and link it?

Here is the code I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.countriesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Saudi Arabia", @"United Arab Emirates", @"Bahrain", nil];
    self.countriesPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self attachPickerToTextField:self.countriesTextfield :self.countriesPicker];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)attachPickerToTextField: (UITextField*) textField :(UIPickerView*) picker{
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.inputView = picker;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.countriesTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.countriesPicker){
        return self.countriesArray.count;
    }
        return 0;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.countriesPicker){
        return [self.countriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return @"???";
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.countriesPicker){
        self.countriesTextfield.text = [self.countriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Comment: This view has the UIPickerView delegate methods, but is it properly hooked up in the storyboard? If not, none of those delegate methods to set up the pickerview will be captured. 

There's nothing about a button - just the creation of a pickerView loaded with the country names from a hard-coded array of options. When a picker row is selected, it puts that country name into the textField. 

The line where it sets `textField.inputView = picker` should be what sets the picker to show up instead of a keyboard. Does it not appear when you click in the textView?

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is only a download page with code for an NSViewController subclass, so there is no context for me to give a thorough answer.  Additionally, the linked code does not match the quoted code in the question (this must be a simplified version?), so my answer below refers to the linked code in which I can at least see where the IBOutlet properties are instantiated.

This code connects two UIPickerViews to two UITextFields.  There is no button and no drop down menu.  From the code on the link it looks like the pickers and textfields are set up and connected in Interface Builder.  I say this because the IBOutlet properties are set internally in the code and they are not exposed in the external interface in the header file.

To make this works as intended, though, so that the UIPickerViews are not visible on load, I think it is necessary to instantiate them in code.  See this answer: [instantiating UIPickerView for UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741173/2715819)

Comment: Where do you see 2? There's only the countriesPicker and the countriesTextfield.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  Will edit to fix.  The answer I gave was based on the linked files, which it seems don't match the quoted code.