# How do i make a picker show up when a user selects a text field

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to swift and have trouble making drop down lists.

I have a story board that needs to contain about 6 questions the user needs to fill in and so far all i have working is picker views and i can only fit 2 or 3 on the screen.

What is the best way to to create a drop down lists in Swift?

Comment: You could always insert a cell when the text box is selected containing a UIPickerView.

Comment: Or `textField.inputView = UIPickerView(...`?

Comment: What do you mean Matthias?

Comment: Matthew, why don't you as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView)?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740874/uipickerview-as-inputview-of-uitextfield ?

Answer (score 0):

For implementing drop down you can use the table view,set its hidden property YES and when user clicks on the text field change hidden property to NO.This is the easiest way to implement drop down using table view in ios.