# Multiple textfield with single picker view in IOS

Tags: ios, tags, uipickerview

I am new to IOS i want to create multiple textfield with only one picker progamatically. Suppose i need five textfield means if i clicked first textfield picker view can load the first array then i go to second textfield means picker view can load second array automatically and goes on upto last field and array.please give me idea and suggestion based on my problem.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20741173/1371853

Comment: Implement Textfield delegate  and change array of picker reload picker view solve your problem

Comment: any detail coding @PKT

Comment: yesterday I answered your question is not work

Comment: not working @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: can you send ur project I will check

Comment: how to send @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
    if (textField == txtText ) {
      self.arrLoadPicker = txtTextArray
    }else  if (textField == currency1 ) {
             self.arrLoadPicker = currency1Array

      }
}

Comment: and dont forgot to reload picker view     [self.thePicker reloadAllComponents];

Comment: @PKT - yesterday I given the all solution, but is not work (questioner replied).

Comment: ok go to sendspace.com , compress your project into zip format and up load the project and send the link

Comment: set picker view as inputview of your textfield ....

Comment: Had u got my Project@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: i tired your suggestion but its not working @PKT

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps to achieve your goal.

1. Download below generic classes from given link:

   [LabeledPickerView.h](https://github.com/kareman/mySettings/blob/master/Code/Generic%20classes/LabeledPickerView.h)

   [LabeledPickerView.m](https://github.com/kareman/mySettings/blob/master/Code/Generic%20classes/LabeledPickerView.m)
2. Copy this class into your project and import **"LabeledPickerView.h"** into your ViewController.h file. Also, Add **UIPickerViewDataSource**, **UIPickerDelegate** and **UITextFieldDelegate**.
3. Now, initialized Picker with following method:-

   ```
   -(LabeledPickerView *)GetPickerViewWithTag:(int)Tag {

      LabeledPickerView *pickerView = [[LabeledPickerView alloc] init];

      pickerView.dataSource = self;

      pickerView.delegate = self;

      pickerView.tag = Tag;

      pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

      pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

      return pickerView;

   }
   ```

   This method will return PickerView's properties.
4. Now, We'll add data into this using UIPickerView Delegate and Data Source Methods as follow:-

   ```
   //Based on the text fields tags, you can populate the data in PickerView.
   -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

        return 1;     //Returns components in PickerView. Change with switch - case statement if you want more components in any of the text fields.
   }

   -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {     

       int tag = (int)((UIPickerView *)pickerView).tag;
       switch (tag) {
             case 10: {
                if (YourArray.count > 0) {
                    return [YourArray count];
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
             }
             default:
             break;
       }
       return 0;
   }

   -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

       int tag = (int)((UIPickerView *)pickerView).tag;
       switch (tag) {
             case 10: {
               if ([YourArray count] > 0) {
                   return [YourArray objectAtIndex:row];
               }
               else {
                   return @"";
               }
               break;
            }
            default:
            break;
        }
        return @"";
    }

   -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

         int tag = (int)((UIPickerView *)pickerView).tag;
         switch (tag) {
               case 10: {
                   if ([YourArray count] > 0) {
                     YourTextField.text = [YourArray objectAtIndex:row];
               }
               else {
                     txtCity.text = @"";
               }
               break;
         }
         default:
         break;
      }
    }
   ```
5. Now, Open Picker When You Start Editing as follow:

   ```
   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       if (textField == firstTextField) {
           LabeledPickerView *picker = [self GetPickerViewWithTag:10];  //Change tag as text field changes..
           textField.inputView = picker;  
           [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
           [self pickerView:picker didSelectRow:0 inComponent:0];
        }
   }
   ```

In this method add as many text fields you have. Do't forget to assign different tags to each text field.

By Using above code, You can use single picker view with multiple text fields.

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: I have made minor changes in code. Please try with this updated code.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you,

i done the same code in my project and it working. here i give you code for three textfields.

```
    NSMutableArray *pickerTitleData, *pickerCityData, *pickerStateData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UItextfield *txtTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UItextfield *txtTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UItextfield *txtTitle;
    UIPickerView *TitleSelect,*CitySelect, *StateSelect;




for address type
        pickerTitleData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Home",@"Office",@"Other", nil];

        TitleSelect = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
        TitleSelect.dataSource = self;
        TitleSelect.delegate = self;
        TitleSelect.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        txtTitle.inputView = TitleSelect;

// same you have three other array


#pragma mark - Picker View Data source for city

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    @try
    {
        if (pickerView == TitleSelect)
        {
            return pickerTitleData.count;
        }

        else if (pickerView == CitySelect)
        {
            return pickerCityData.count;
        }

        else if (pickerView == StateSelect)
        {
            return pickerStateData.count;
        }

        return 1;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"exception--%@",exception.description);
    }
}

#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate for city

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    @try
    {
        if (pickerView == TitleSelect)
        {
            [txtTitle setText:[pickerTitleData objectAtIndex:row]];
        }

        else if (pickerView == CitySelect)
        {
            [txtTownOrCity setText:[pickerCityData objectAtIndex:row]];
        }

        else if (pickerView == StateSelect)
        {
            [txtState setText:[pickerStateData objectAtIndex:row]];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception.description);
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    @try
    {
        if (pickerView == TitleSelect)
        {
            return pickerTitleData[row];
        }

        else if (pickerView == CitySelect)
        {
            return pickerCityData[row];
        }

        else if (pickerView == StateSelect)
        {
            return pickerStateData[row];
        }

        return @"";

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception.description);
    }
}
```

Comment: i had one dought in your coding why all textfield name same? @PALAK iOS Developer