# Hiding keyboard in view with multiple text fields in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, keyboard, textfield

I have 3 text fields and a pickerView which unhides when one of these fields (`m_unit`) is active so i'm trying to hide keyboard for this one:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        save_button.isEnabled = false
        if textField == self.m_unit {
            self.drop_down.isHidden = false
            textField.endEditing(true)
        }
```

Works fine if there's no other editing text field when tapping `m_unit`. In this case keyboard does not disappear. In other words when I tap some text field, it shows keyboard, then i tap `m_unit` field, but keyboard stays. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems you want to display `UIPickerView` instead of the keyboard for that given textfield (`m_unit`) I would use different approach :)

You can set the UIPickerView as inputView for `UITextField` (in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`)

```
self.m_unit.inputView = yourPickerView
```

You can also check this question:
[UIPickerView as inputView of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740874/uipickerview-as-inputview-of-uitextfield)
which might be duplicate of yours ;)

Comment: I added this line to `viewDidLoad`, but got an error when tapped m_unit textfield. Console: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7f9bc7d27b10> should have parent view controller:<recipe_resizer.ingredientViewController: 0x7f9bc7c04700> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7f9bc88ae400>'

Comment: You have probably already added the `UIPickerView` as a subview of your `UIViewController`'s view. If this is not the problem I will have a look futher.

Comment: :) i didn't get i need to delete the view itself, thanks. a lot better, but somehow picker is now missing data. trying to figure out why

Comment: forgot to delegate

Answer (score 0):

`textField.resignFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        save_button.isEnabled = false
        if textField == self.m_unit {
            textField.resignFirstResponder() 
            self.drop_down.isHidden = false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. picker view textfield false

   ```
     func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   //print("While entering the characters this method gets called")

   if(textField == pickerViewTextField){
       return false;
      }

     return true;
    }
   ```
2. User textfield delegate  bellow code hide  keyboard on press return

   ```
     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
    }
   ```
3. Don't Forget to use UITextFieldDelegate